# Why is numCapabilities a pure function?

Tags: haskell, standard-library

In the concurrency library GHC.Conc there is a function called [`numCapabilities`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/GHC-Conc.html#v%3anumCapabilities).  Its type is `numCapabilities :: Int` and it actually returns some number you passed by the command line flag (e.g. `5` if the options are `+RTS -N 5`).

However, [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v%3agetArgs) (type: `IO [String]`) does essentially the same (it returns the unparsed non-runtime arguments) but isn't a pure function.

If the only excuse is that `numCapabilities` is often needed in pure code, in what way aren't other command line options *not* needed in pure code?

Am I something missing or is either `numCapabilities` a design flaw or am I allowed to write  the following monster?

```
myGetArgs = unsafePerformIO getArgs
```

Comment: I'm now wondering the opposite: Since the value of `getArgs` never changes during the run of your program, I'm not exactly sure why it needs to/should be in `IO`.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, it depends on how one defines a _pure_ expression. I'd define an expression to be _pure_ iff it doesn't depend on anything but the expression itself. By this definition `numCapabilities` isn't pure, so having a type of `Int` should be considered as a design flaw. You may be interested in Conal Elliott's blog post [Notions of purity in Haskell](http://conal.net/blog/posts/notions-of-purity-in-haskell).

Comment: `numCapabilities` need not return the value given to `-N` - it just calls `getNumCapabilities`, so returns however many capabilities there are at the time. I think of this as a bug, really, but it's hard to say what guarantees you can rely on in the GHC modules.

Comment: (Notice that Control.Concurrent exports `getNumCapabilities` but not `numCapabilities`. If you stick to the "standard" interface, you don't see the impurity.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've seen very varying views on what to do in situations like this. Some think that values that might vary between **compiles** should not be pure, and some think that as long as a value doesn't change during your program's local run-time (i.e. after some "configuration" has been "set up" in `main`), it should be pure.

The `base` package seems to have settled on a middle-ground. `numCapabilities` *will not* (as far as I know) change during run-time, but `getArgs` *might*.

This is because there is a [`withArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v:withArgs) function that changes the args you get via `getArgs`. So, that answers that.

Comment: What about [`setNumCapabilities`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/GHC-Conc.html#v:setNumCapabilities)?

Comment: `numCapabilities` returns the parameter to `-N#`, while `getNumCapabilities` returns how many capabilities there actually are. `setNumCapabilities` changes the actual number, which is retrieved by `getNumCapabilities`. Both of the `get*` and `set*` functions are in the `IO` monad.

Comment: Which leads to the question why there are both `numCapabilities` and `getNumCapabilities` and not both `args` and `getArgs`

Comment: Because `setNumCapabilities` was added after `numCapabilities`, and `numCapabilities` is deprecated (as in, the library author says that you should use the `get*` function in the documentation for `numCapabilities`).

Comment: `numCapabilities` doesn't actually return the parameter to `-N#`, cf. my answer. This means that the answer is (partially) incorrect too.

Comment: It's a deprecated value. It definitely used to return the parameter passed to `-N#` before, since it was impossible to change that number (because there was no `setNumCapabilities`). After the new functions were introduced, `numCapabilities` was deprecated, and is only kept for compatibility, so it does still behave consistently for programs that are not aware of `set*`. You should not use it for new programs; in other words, a program containing both `numCapabilities` and `setNumCapabilities` is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 15):

Oh *dear*. If you look at the definition of `numCapabilities`, you can see it is just:

```
numCapabilities :: Int
numCapabilities = unsafePerformIO $ getNumCapabilities
```

and the following ghci sessions illustrate the problem:

```
[ben@euler ~]$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading [...]
ghci> :m +GHC.Conc
ghci> numCapabilities
1
ghci> setNumCapabilities 2
ghci> numCapabilities
1
ghci> :q
Leaving GHCi.

[ben@euler ~]$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading [...]
ghci> :m +GHC.Conc
ghci> setNumCapabilities 2
ghci> numCapabilities
2
```

This is *definitely* bad - the value of `numCapabilities` depends on when it is evaluated with respect to any `setNumCapabilities` calls that may exist in your program. Note that in the first session, `numCapabilities` remained consistent, since the `IO` is only executed the first time it is evaluated. However, in the presence of inlining (the name isn't marked NOINLINE or anything) even that may not be true - you could in principle get two different values from two occurrences of `numCapabilities` (although in practice I haven't been able to make this happen).

So the answer is that `numCapabilities` *isn't* a pure function, but is erroneously marked as such by the notorious back door of `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's a mistake, but it depends on what one thinks purity is. See the post [*Notions of purity in Haskell*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/notions-of-purity-in-haskell/) and its discussion. Simply put, the post's argument is that types have meaning, and there is not room in the meaning of `Int` for something like `numCapabilities`, which is execution-context-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

[`numCapabilities`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Conc.html#v%3anumCapabilities) gives the initial value of `getNumCapabilities`, wether or not the RTS -N flag argument is present, so the type should be the same.

Have you tried it with a higher number than your computer max. simultaneous threads ?

```
$ ghci +RTS -N99
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +GHC.Conc
Prelude GHC.Conc> numCapabilities
99
Prelude GHC.Conc> getNumCapabilities
99   !!!
```