# Why are getArgs and getProgName IO actions?

Tags: haskell, io, command-line-arguments, referential-transparency

I'm a complete newbie currently trying to learn Haskell with "[Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)". I've reach [the section explaining how to work with command line arguments](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#command-line-arguments), and something is bugging me.

From my understanding (and [haskell.org's definition](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_Haskell_IO/Actions)), actions are meant to encapsulate side effects. Command line arguments being immutable inputs for a given instance of the program, then what is the point of having `getProgName :: IO String` rather than `getProgName :: String`? Differently put: what's the point of preventing a pure function from calling `getProgName`?

**Update**

I had some great answers to this question so far. I'm accepting [Don Stewart's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296155/451980) as the most simple and concise, but [Conal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296888/451980) (with its associated [blog post](http://conal.net/blog/posts/is-haskell-a-purely-functional-language/)) is definitely worth a read.

Comment: A rule of thumb I like to use is that any pure value could be completely evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firstly, `getArgs` can change at runtime. See [`withArgs`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Environment.html#v:withArgs).

Secondly, `getArgs` and `getProgName` fall into an interesting class of impure computations - they are thought of as constants during a program run, however, they're are not values available at compile time, and they change from one program run to another. They don't have a clean denotation.

See e.g. earlier [discussions](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-October/016574.html), where getArgs, and floating point computations are discussed. And even minBound/maxBound can be thought to be in this class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Your book is next in the reading list btw (I actually started with it, but had to fallback on something simpler to begin with).

Answer (score 24):

To answer such questions, you'll need a foundation:
what does it mean that an expression `e` has type `t`?
You could give arbitrary answers for primitives like `getProgName`, but you don't have to.
Instead, look at the *meanings* of expressions and of types.
Say that an expression `e` has type `t` when the value denoted by `e` (i.e., the meaning of `e` as a mathematical value) belongs to the collection denoted by `t`.

Now consider `t == String`.
What meaning do we want `String` to have?
Again, there's a lot of room for choice here.
However, there's a lot of merit in choosing the useful candidate with the simplest mathematical definition.
In Haskell `String == [Char]`, so we're really talking about the meanings of `[]` and `Char`
The most compelling simple candidates I know of are that `[]` denotes lists (sequences), and `Char` denotes characters, and consequently that `String` denotes sequences of characters, i.e., "strings".

With the choice that `String` means strings, now we're in a position to ask whether it's possible that `getProgName :: String`.
If so then the meaning of `getProgName` must be a sequence of characters.
However, there is no *single* sequence of characters that captures the intent behind `getProgName`.
(*Edit*: Presumably, you want `getProgName` to yield different strings when it appears in differently-named programs.)
Therefore, we have to either choose a different type, such as (but not necessarily) `IO String`, or we have to choose a more complicated meaning for `String`.
The latter route might at first seem appealing, until you consider the deep implications.
Purely functional (more accurately "denotative") programming supports practical, rigorous reasoning thanks to using *simple* meanings like sequences rather than complex meanings like functions from some sort of environment including operating system, machine execution context.

For closely related remarks and discussion, see the blog post [*Notions of purity in Haskell*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/notions-of-purity-in-haskell/).

*Edit:* I think Peter Landin (grandfather of Haskell) expressed it best with his definition of "denotative programming" (or "genuinely functional programming"), which he recommended as a substantive replacement to vague terms like "declarative" and "functional" programming.
For a reference, quotations, and brief commentary, see [this comment](http://conal.net/blog/posts/is-haskell-a-purely-functional-language#comment-35882) in the post [*Is Haskell a purely functional language?*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/is-haskell-a-purely-functional-language/).

Comment: This is all very nice, until you consider why `numCapabilities` is pure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851005/why-is-numcapabilities-a-pure-function

Comment: I have considered those reasons. As I mentioned in an answer to that post, I consider `numCapabilities :: Int` a mistake for the very reasons I outlined above and in the blog post: there is no single integer that corresponds to the intended meaning of `numCapabilities`. I've not seen any semantic basis for the justification of the assigned type.

Comment: To play devils advocate, what do you think about the sin function?   Or even (+)?  These are bound late to whatever hardware you happen to be running on, so, e.g., sin can vary between Intel and AMD.

Comment: @augustss: I was surprised & disappointed to learn that Haskell's numeric types do have language-defined (implementation-independent) semantics.

Comment: @augustss Oops -- I dropped a word. Make that "types do *not* have language-defined ...".

Comment: IMO, Haskell should have types with language defined semantics, like Integer (language defined modulo memory) and Word32, but also machine specific ones like Double.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is pure functions are pure because you can reason with them at "code time", and the compiler can, at compile time. IO actions are runtime dependent. `getArgs`, which gives arguments to a program only when it is run, is hence an IO action.

As Learn you a Haskell puts it:

> You can think of an I/O action as a box with little feet that will go
>   out into the real world and do something there (like write some
>   graffiti on a wall) and maybe bring back some data.

We don't know what the box with little feet will bring in at code time or compile time.

Comment: With this "compile time" criterion, I gather that the meaning of a program could change from one compilation to another. For instance, there might be `compilationTimeAndPlace :: String`. I wouldn't want to allow such a thing, since the intended meaning of `compilationTimeAndPlace` isn't a string of characters but rather something much more complicated, like a function from some sort of compilation context to a string of characters.
See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295582/why-are-getargs-and-getprogname-io-actions/14296888#14296888) for more.